# Are there distinct primes $p,q$ satisfying $pq=(2^r-1)(p+q)-5$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We let $p\neq q$ be odd prime numbers and $r$ be integer $>2$.
Are there such $p,q$ satisfying $pq=(2^r-1)(p+q)-5$?

This is clear from here that,

$q(p-2^r+1)=(2^r-1)p-5$,

and $p(q-2^r+1)=(2^r-1)q-5$.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is clear, but what do the last two equations represent?  Also, please use LaTeX formatting - it's easier on the eyes :)

Comment: I don't know how to use latex. Those equations are equivalent to the first one (other forms to present the equation).

Comment: I fixed my question above (questions => equations).  You can use LaTeX by just putting equations in dollar signs (i.e. `$y = x^2$` gives $y = x^2$).

Comment: Didn't write that p does not equal q

Comment: Actually you mean $q (p - 2^r + 1) = (2^r - 1) p - 5$ and
$p (q - 2^r + 1) = (2^r - 1) q - 5$.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my bad mistakes. This is what I was about to write.

Comment: I wrote a quick script and found that $p = q = 5$ is the only solution where $p$ and $q$ are both less than 5000.

Comment: Great, but as D.Shnaks said: "10^50 is a long way from infinity". :)

Comment: I don't think that it helps, but for any solutions bot $p,q$ have to be 1 mod 4.

Comment: It is true but does not seem to be helpful..

Comment: If there is a solution, one of the primes must be 3.

Comment: How can you show such thing? This also contradicts that both primes are 1 mod 4.

Comment: There are only a couple of integer solutions less than $30000$ for each $r$ with $3\le r \le 9$ (but no primes), and no solutions for $10\le r \le 30$. Not that it proves anything.

Comment: @tomerg: Check both sides in respect to modulo 3.

Comment: I still don't see it.

Comment: @user: We have three very inconsistent comments so far. User says that both p and q must be $1 \mod{4}$, tpv says one of the primes must be 3, and MartianInvader notes that 5,5 is a solution if we allow p to equal q. Why do both have to be 1 mod 4?

Comment: Because from the equation we have: $(p+1)(q+1)=2^r(p+q)-4$ which gives p,q are not -1 mod 4. This leads that p,q are 1 mod 4.

Comment: Oh, my bad :S, sorry. Forgot the -1 in $(2^r-1)$, so what I wrote is not correct at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over at tomerg's other, closely-related question [The form $xy+5=a(x+y)$ and its solutions with $x,y$ prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36694/the-form-xy5-axy-and-its-solutions-with-x-y-prime/36839#comment-82440) I found $p=17179929661$, $q=4880269588100161$, $r=34$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote **EDIT: After writing, the original problem was edited to read $p(q - 2^r - 1)...$ and so this is all beautiful speculation on a different problem. Had I checked his derivation, I might have noticed. But I didn't.**

Firstly, I wonder - is there a significance to this question? I've no idea. But I put together some scratch work real quick and found a solution - so there's that.

I note firstly that at most one can be even (considering the equation mod 2 gives this). So I thought, what if p were 2?

Then we have $$ 2(q + 2^r - 1) = (2^r - 1)1 - 5$$
$$ 2^{r+1} + 3 = (2^r - 3)q$$
$$ \frac{2^{r+1} + 3}{2^r - 3} = q $$

And if $ r = 2$, we get that $ q = 11$. Although I don't have it yet, I suspect this is the only solution for q for $p = 2$. So there is at least one answer.

Without having a better intuition for the problem (as I don't really know if there's anything special about this equation, if it means something in particular, etc.), I don't see a better method of attack than this sort of play.

Comment: @mixedmath: the question requires $p$ and $q$ be odd.

Comment: Okay, I responded to the original, unedited post. This is too bad. It's still fun, though not applicable to this question. But upon checking, even then they were to be odd. I really just outdid myself on this one.

Comment: $r=1$ also works, if you allow $q=-7$.

Comment: Still r>1 and by prime numbers I mean these are>1.

Comment: Also, $y=(2x+3)/(x-3)$ is an integer iff $x-3$ divides $9$ iff $x=-6,0,2,4,6,12$ iff $y=1,-1,-7,11,5,3$.

Comment: @lhf: How do we know that $(x-3)|9$ iff y is an integer?

Comment: $(2x+3)/(x-3)=2+9/(x-3)$.

Comment: @lhf: Oh! How nice!